# In BizTalk, unable to send file from local to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, biztalk, sharepoint-online, biztalk-2016

As the title says, I am trying to send files from local directory to a SharePoint online site with BizTalk. I am unable to do so for days and days... read tons of topic about it but nothing is working, I am a bit discouraged to be honest at the moment...

Here is how my send port is currently configured :

[image]

The account used has full access granted on the SharePoint site. I can log in with it using a browser without any issue, I can upload files as well.

Here is the error I encounter when trying to send a file :

[image]

I am using BizTalk 2016 with SharePoint Online.

If someone has an idea on how I could resolve this, I would be very very grateful.

Comment: Have you made the registry changes to make the server use TLS 1.2 or have a custom endpoint behaviour to do the same?   That sort of error occurs when BizTalk is using an older version of TLS still.

Comment: What do you mean by custom endpoint behaviour ? I am using the transport type "Windows SharePoint Services", I can't configure a behaviour

Comment: True, you can't with the Windows Sharepoint Server adapter, I even wrote a blog post which lists which ones you can do it with.  https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/biztalk-sso-sso-affiliate-settings/

Answer (score 1):

BizTalk, or rather the .Net layer defaults to using older TLS protocols, namely TLS 1.0, and doesn't then negotiate up.

To address this you need make sure you have CU5 for BizTalk Server 2016 or [later](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/service-pack-and-cumulative-update-list-for-biztalk-server-108e5e94-4558-8b57-d5fb-45984506d56f) (currently CU8) and then follow the steps in "Option 1: Switch to the TLS 1.2 protocol" section of the following article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:" as per the article [Support for TLS 1.2 protocol in BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-tls-1-2-protocol-in-biztalk-server-b142db9a-d071-3d7e-401e-2b2d3d6686ff)

[3155464](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/ms16-065-description-of-the-tls-ssl-protocol-information-disclosure-vulnerability-cve-2016-0149-may-10-2016-7af955c4-ac73-6c50-dfbb-8267e6284df5) MS16-065: Description of the TLS/SSL protocol information disclosure vulnerability (CVE-2016-0149): May 10, 2016

or

Use the scripts from the following [Setup Microsoft Windows or IIS for SSL Perfect Forward Secrecy and TLS 1.2](https://www.hass.de/content/setup-microsoft-windows-or-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12)

Note: You will have to test to make sure no other system BizTalk connects to still uses TLS 1.0 or 1.1, and if so not to disable those, but to try to default to 1.2.

Comment: I finally managed to make it works using TLS 1.2 as suggested above but another issue that is currently remaining is that it seems that the biztalk sharepoint adapter uses legagy authentication but our sharepoint admins want to disable this property. When legacy auth is off, it doesn't work anymore... Did you ever seen this case and do you know how to work around it ? thanks again

Comment: @Gosfly You might want to post that as a new question